# SQL / how to update multiple values of 1 column in sql depending on her values and the values of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, case

How to update the values of a column exp : **cl1**  depending on her values (cl1) and the values of another column exp :  **FL**  IN SQLSERVER??
example :

```
1- if cl1 = '15g0' then 20gs 
if cl1 = '22g0' then 22gs 
if cl1 = '14rx' then 14rs 

2- WHERE  FL = ' m31' OR FL= 'm28'
```

i tried it  with 'case' but it didn't work

```
update table 
set
cl1 = (case when cl1 = '15g0' then 20gs end ),
cl1 = (case when cl1 = '22g0' then 22gs end ),
cl1 = (case when cl1 = '11rx' then 14rs end )

where( FL like 'm31' ) or ( FL like 'm28')
```

Comment: is it t-SQL or Mysql ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Update cl1` in a single `case` statement and add single quotes around values as below:

```
UPDATE table 
SET cl1 = (CASE WHEN cl1 = '15g0' THEN '20gs'
                WHEN cl1 = '22g0' THEN '22gs'
                WHEN cl1 = '11rx' THEN '14rs' END)
WHERE ( FL LIKE 'm31' ) OR ( FL LIKE 'm28')
```

Comment: Welcome !! @Ouskiffprog

Comment: sorry i will change the score  when i have more than 15 reputation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Update in a single `case` statement , also have to include single quotes

```
update table 
set
cl1 = case  when cl1 = '15g0' then '20gs' 
            when cl1 = '22g0' then '22gs' 
            when cl1 = '11rx' then '14rs' end 
where( FL = 'm31' ) or ( FL = 'm28')
```